# Powershell get string after slash

Tags: powershell

I have a text file where I only want to have the word after a slash "/

Example : hello/world

And I just want everything that comes after / in my example only "world" I started as follows :

```
Get-Content .\myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-replace` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) for this. Below will replace all characters until and include the first `/` on each line. Lines that don't match will not be altered.

```
# Example with one line
'hello/world' -replace '^.*?/'

# Example reading each line of a text file
(Get-Content .\myfile.txt) -replace '^.*?/'
```

If you want to remove all characters until and including the last `/` on each line, you can use a greedy match `.*`:

```
(Get-Content .\myfile.txt) -replace '^.*/'
```

You can apply the same concepts above and treat the entire file as a single string with the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content`. This would allow you to remove all characters before the first occurrence of `/` or the last occurrence of `/`. All you need to add is the single-line modifier syntax `(?s)`, which allows `.` to match newline characters:

```
# Remove Up Until First /
(Get-Content .\myfile.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s)^.*/'

# Remove Up Until Last /
(Get-Content .\myfile.txt -Raw) -replace '(?s).*/'
```

**Explanation:**

`^` indicates the beginning of the string. `.*?` is the lazy match for all characters. Since we have a succeeding `/`, it will then lazily match up until a `/` is found. Since no replacement string is provided, the matched characters are just removed.

However, it may help to dial in the regex string to cover only the exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

here is a somewhat different method. [*grin*] it uses the built in `Split-Path` cmdlet.

```
$InString = 'Hello/World'
$FinalPart = Split-Path -Path $InString -Leaf

$FinalPart
```

output = `World`